# How to Setup Multiple Signing Keys on One Machine for BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-webworks

I am developing some BlackBerry apps for different companies and they each want their apps published under their own vendor portal with their own signing keys.

How can I setup the signing keys for the different accounts on the same machine?

Will I need multiple installs of WebWorks SDK (each with different signing keys for the sign tool)? That is the only option I can really think of, but I was hoping there might be a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to install multiple SDK's.